# Ubuntu keeps crashing when I play any Steam game

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, steam

Whenever I play any Steam game, my computer crashes randomly. It's the only way it does it.

The drivers are already upgraded and it's so annoying, I can't play :(

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and my laptop has Intel Core 17-5500U @3.0GHz. My GPU is a NVIDIA Geforce 920M.

Please help!!!

Comment: Can you run `steam` in the terminal and edit your question to include the error messages you see?

Comment: Thermal issues, corrupt memory or faulty GPU maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Steam.
Reinstall Steam.

**if that still doesn't work**

See which dependencies Steam relies on.
Reinstall dependency. (careful!)

**if that still doesn't work**

Do check that you have the drivers properly installed.

My apologies that my answer isn't more specific.
I wish I had more specifics :)

Best of luck.